# Pygame memory leak with transform.flip

Tags: memory, pygame

I came across an interesting issue writing a little side scroller today. Instead of a sprite sheet I planned to use single pictures for the animations as I'm lacking a good "packer" for creating sprite sheets (and honestly, also the patience and passion as it's only a test project).

Anyways, I created a list of the 8 PNGs (with transparency) depicting the walk animation to the right side. I deemed it a good idea to prepare the flipped images for walking to the left side also in the constructor and not frame-wise when the game is running (flip really consumes a lot of CPU as I measured).

using a for loop, I get a memory leak

```
self.move_l = [##List of 8 PNG images with transparency for moving right]

self.move_r = []
for img in self.move_l:
    self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False)
```

Error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python34\_Projects\efg\efg.py", line 196, in <module>
    Main = MainProgram((1024, 680))
  File "D:\Python34\_Projects\efg\efg.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.player = actors.Player(screen_size)
  File "D:\Python34\_Projects\efg\actors.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(img, True, False))
pygame.error: Out of memory
```

When I add each image seperately, it works perfectly:

```
self.move_r = []
self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(self.move_l[0], True, False))
self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(self.move_l[1], True, False))
self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(self.move_l[2], True, False))
self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(self.move_l[3], True, False))
self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(self.move_l[4], True, False))
self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(self.move_l[5], True, False))
self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(self.move_l[6], True, False))
self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(self.move_l[7], True, False))
```

Does anybody have a clue what makes the difference between adding them one by one and using a for loop?
I also tried a while loop:

```
_index = 0
while len(self.move_r) < len(self.move_l):
    self.move_r.append(pygame.transform.flip(self.move_l[_index], True, False))
    _index += 1
```

This also worked, no memory leak. I'm wondering what the difference is between the two latter solutions - appending one by one and using a while loop - to the for loop (which I thought should even be faster and more efficient than a while loop).

I'll appreciate any hints. The problem for my game is solved (I can either use the while loop or append one by one), but I'm really curious about what could cause such behaviour.

Thanks

Patric

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! In another portion of the code (not shown here) the image was also added to the self.move_l array, so the source array would continuously growing longer which would result in the leak of memory.

So the for loop, the while loop and the separated addition would all work with the for loop as most efficient according to my measurements.